# Python : How to update a row if it exists else make an Insert in a CSV file

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to perform the below operations in python 2.7.

1. If CSV file (test.csv) doesn't exist, create one else append.
2. Insert or Update the CSV file

*File contents:*

111,03/11/2019,ABC

112,04/11/2019,XYZ

222,01/11/2019,UVW

*Insert scenario :*

Input : 223,01/11/2019,YYY
This should get inserted as there is no matching key (i.e. the first column:: 111,112,222)

*Update scenario:*

Input :111,03/11/2019,ZZZ
This should replace the first row.

Sharing a part of the code :

```
import csv

ID=111
Year="03/11/2019"
Code_word="XXX"


with open('xyz.csv'.replace('.csv', '$BKP.csv'), 'w+') as CSV, open('xyz.csv'.replace('.csv', '$BKP.csv'), 'w') as CSV_BKP:
   csvWrite=csv.writer(CSV)
   csv_bkpWrite = csv.writer(CSV_BKP)
   for row in CSV:
      if row[0] == ID:
         print row
         csvWrite.writerow([ID,Year,Code_word])
      else:
         csv_bkpWrite.writerow([ID,Year,Code_word])
```

Comment: What exception you are facing and where is your effort in achieving this ?

Comment: I am able to make a new insert but unable to make update to it.

Comment: share the code to help where the issue is.

Comment: Sharing a part of the code in the description

Comment: in order to check if a file exists or not use os python package.  if not if(os.path.exists('test.csv')):
    os.mknod('test.csv')

Comment: Is your .csv file going to be so large that it can't be loaded into memory? When you say 'insert', I assume this means you need the resulting file to always be sorted? In your example, the text is always the same length, but I assume that the text at the end could be any length? In your example, the first field is a number, would this always be a number, or could it be any string / text?

Comment: The best way to do this is probably to load the entire CSV and modify it in Python, using something like Pandas, and then write the result to CSV.

Comment: @Grismar File will be large. I will contain around 25K rows.
I need the resulting file to always be sorted.
Yes, the text at the end could be any length.
1st field is always a number.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Thanks for the suggestion, I will try with that as well

Comment: Forgot to add that variable names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: 25k lines actually means that the file won't even exceed a megabyte, so from a coding perspective it's small, it will easily fit in memory on most devices.